# Application for Windows tablet using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

We have this rather big and complex line-of-business system that has multiple desktop applications and 3 or 4 web portals deployed in the intranet but also outside, for the external users of the system.

Towards the end of the project, we have received some additional change requests to add 3 small applications that are supposed to work on some Windows 8.1  Pro Dell Tablets. One of the requirements that were given to us is to use Windows Authentication to identify the current user of the application. The system we built contains an SQL Server database at its core, so these 3 new tablet apps would have to serve data coming from there.

I am trying to figure out what's the best way to proceed while designing and developing these three small apps.

On one hand, I have the option of developing a Windows Store application. I won't be able to use Entity Framework (as I did for some of the desktop XAML applications) but I can build some RESTful Web API that I can consume. However, I read that Windows Store apps cannot easily be used in conjunction with Windows Authentication (some are saying that is downright impossible to have Windows Authentication in WinStore apps) so that seems to be a major show-stopper for us right now.

On the other hand, I could build a regular WPF application that would allow me to use EF and Windows Authentication with no issues. But I would be missing the functionality to tap, swipe, pinch and all the other great touch features that are available for Windows Store apps for tablets, features that I believe our client would expect. There is Telerik's UI for WPF, but that would add more costs to the client and I am not even sure the API will give me the entire functionality available out of the box in WinRT.

Has anyone found a way to marry the best of both worlds?

EDIT: Upon further research, I found out that Windows Store applications can be sideloaded, which is a way to bypass the Windows Store. So now I only need to figure out if sideloaded apps can use Integrated Security on a Windows 8 Pro tablet.

Comment: Are you using AD for authentication ?

Comment: Yes, the client uses Active Directory to authenticate all the users of the system.

Comment: I am currently working on a similar topic, the same problematics. I'll try to make you my solution as a response. you should wait until tomorrow because it is very late in Paris. ;) Bonne nuit

Comment: So were you able to authenticate a sideloaded app in your AD?

Comment: Yes , i did it. I will give you my answer right now

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1) use the Azure AD authentication Library (ADAL) : The ADAL Client Enables Application developers to Easily authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), 
And Then obtenir access tokens for Securing API calls. 
ADAL HAS Many features authentication That Make Easier for developers, Such As asynchronous support, a configurable caching That token stores access tokens tokens and refresh, 
automatic refresh token expires When an access token and a refresh token is available, and more. By handling MOST of the complexity, ADAL can help a developer focus on business 
logic implementation and In Their Easily secure resources without Being an expert on security.
here you will not find step how to connect to AD using ADAL
https://www.nimbo.com/blog/use-azure-active-directory-adal-windows-store-app/

2) Using .Net Framework. Create à WCF Service in local et use this :

```
public bool AuthenticateUserService(string path, string user, string pass)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    try {
        //run a search using those credentials.  
        //If it returns anything, then you're authenticated
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ds.FindOne();
        return true;
    } catch {
        //otherwise, it will crash out so return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

then you consume this service from your Windows Store App.

Comment: This ADAL seems extremely interesting. I am going to look into it. Since I asked the question, I continued my research and I discovered that in the Applications' Manifest, in the Capabilities tab, I can set the Enterprise Authentication flag. Have you tried that? If you did, why was it not enough? At this point, my plan is to develop a Win 8 application with Enterprise Authentication capabilities. I will sideload that application on all my client's tablets and will have the application access the data layer via a RESTful API. I hope this approach will work.